# Snort detect file access of exisiting files

Tags: snort

I've allready got a working rule for accessing files of a specific format (pcre). The problem is, that the rule also fires for files, that match the pattern, but don't exist. Now the rule should only fire, if the file exists. I had an idea to solve this by checking the server response (if 404 -> file doesn't exist), but I didn't found a way to do that. Does anyone know how to that or has an idea how I can check with snort if a file really exists on the server?

Answer (score 0):

If found a solution: it's possible to use flowbits to have a dependendy between multiple rules.